# Can cyclic shifts of ABAB and ABBA be equal?

Tags: combinatorics, combinatorics-on-words

Do there exist binary strings $A$ and $B$ so that:

1. the word $ABAB$ is a cyclic shift of $ABBA$ and
2. the word $AB$ does not equal $BA$?

Here $AB$ represents the concatenation of $A$ and $B$.

Comment: Hint: If $ABAB$ is a cyclic shift of $ABBA$, then there exist two strings $S$ and $Q$ such that $SQ=ABBA$ and $QS=ABAB$.  This means that Either $|S|\le|AB|$ or $|Q|\le|AB|$, so there exists some string $R$ such that either $QR=AB$ or $SR=AB$.  That should be enough to get you started.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No; note that any cyclic shift of $ABAB$ still has the property that it is some sequence repeated twice. If this is equal to $ABBA$, then the repeated sequence is equal to both $AB$ and $BA$, contradicting that these are different.